# IO.Open no acepta una variable como argumento

Tags: lua

Primero daros las gracias por la asistencia que brindáis, aprendo mucho con vosotros, yo estoy empezando, así que paciencia por favor. :)

**Que quiero conseguir**
Quiero conseguir el *nombre archivo + extensión* desde una ruta de archivo.
Abrir el archivo y leer un dato que necesito para saber que método
Digamos que cada objeto utiliza el mismo archivo pero con configuraciones diferentes, es como un archivo setting, su nombre es: nombre objeto + extensión (.fxp), ej: si es una mesa pues *mesa.fxp*
Cuando consiga estos datos y sepa que script utiliza, podré abrir el archivo del objeto en cuestión, digamos que usa el script *mueve mesa.lua* , entonces abriré el script, lo leeré y podré tomar nota de todas las variables globales que utiliza.
El problema es que yo no sé de antemano que archivos utiliza el usuario, por lo que debo averiguarlo todo.

**Que he hecho hasta ahora**

```
g_itemPath = {}
local meshPath = ""
local nonSpace = "aimain=ani_start.lua"  -- aimain        = ani_start.lua
local indexOfChar = 0
local indexOfChar1 = 0
local fh = ""
local fho = ""
local line = ""
local plrFlag = "_markers\\player start.fpe"
local lenPath = 0
local strSearch = ""

function getpath_init(e)
end

function getpath_main(e)

    for n = 1,g_EntityElementMax,1 do
    if g_Entity[n] ~= nil then
        g_itemPath[n] = GetEntityFilePath(n)

        if g_itemPath[n] ~= plrFlag then 
            meshPath = tostring(g_itemPath[n])      

            --Prompt(meshPath)

    if meshPath ~= "" then 
        lenPath = string.len(meshPath)
        indexOfChar = string.find(meshPath,"\\", 1) + 1 
        indexOfChar1 = string.find(meshPath,"\\", indexOfChar) + 1
    if indexOfChar1 ~= nil then
        meshPath = string.sub(meshPath,indexOfChar1,lenPath)
        --Prompt(meshPath .." - " ..indexOfChar1)   
        --meshPath = tostring(meshPath)
        --strSearch = '"' ..meshPath ..'"'
        strSearch = string.format('%q', meshPath)

    --if strSearch ~= nil then
        -- local f = assert(io.open(filename, mode))
        fh = assert(io.open(strSearch,"r")) 
        io.output(fh)
    --end

        fho = io.open("globalvars_list.txt","w+")
        io.input(fho)

        --while true do
        if fh ~= nil then line = fh:read() end
        if line == nil then break end       
            line = line:gsub("%s+", "")
            line = string.gsub(line, "%s+", "")     
        if string.find(line,nonSpace) then
            fho:write(line)
            fho:write("\n")
        end
        --end


        if fh ~= nil then
            fh:close()
            fho:close()
        end 

    end 
    end     
    end 
        Prompt("line: " ..line)
    end
    end
end
```

este es un ejemplo de como cada usuario establece este valor a su manera, en el ejemplo hay un gran número de espacios, ejemplo:
local nonSpace = "aimain       =    ani_start.lua" 
Por lo que decidí primero que todo eliminar todos los espacios, obtener algo como : "aimain=ani_start.lua" .

Una vez conseguido esto, buscar dicha palabra en el archivo "aimain" leyendo el archivo linea por linea, y cuando la encuentre que suprima todos los espacios de la linea y obtener el nombre archivo sin espacios, para poder obtener el nombre del script que utiliza, en este caso "ani_start.lua", una vez tengo el nombre del script abrirlo y obtener todas las variables globales que utiliza el archivo, para poder re-inicial izarlas en el siguiente nivel, que será leído por el motor de juegos y actualizará todas las variables globales con sus valores correspondientes, en el siguiente nivel.

**Cual es el problema**

*line = fh:read()* arroja un error: argumento no valido + nombre archivo, es como si estuviera utilizando un valor nil como argumento en:
fh = assert(io.open(strSearch,"r")) 
No obstante yo he usado un print para verificarlo y el nombre de archivo obtenido es correcto, con su extensión y todo, debo añadir que se trata de un archivo de texto, aunque no sea txt, como un ,dat o ,log, no debe ser un problema para abrirlo.

Ya sé que io.open quiere una cadena de texto pura y dura, si yo ahora mismo uso el nombre de archivo en lugar de la variable, funciona a la primera, pero es que yo no sé de antemano el nombre de archivo, debo averiguarlo, guardar dicho valor en una variable string y pasarlo como argumento.
También debo añadir que no se necesita la ruta de archivo completa, solo el nombre archivo + extensión.

Incluso formateo el valor a string para estar más seguros : strSearch = string.format('%q', meshPath) y nada, que no hay manera.
Incluso uso tostring : meshPath = tostring(g_itemPath[n])

Pero no el quiere: fh = assert(io.open("miarchivo.txt","r"))
O quiere: meshPath = "miarchivo.txt"
 y yo no puedo darselo, yo solo puedo pasar una variable como argumento, por que yo no puedo saber de antemano como se llama el archivo, solo puedo obtenerlo a través de la ruta de archivo, que la obtengo a su vez con el meto interno: GetEntityFilePath().

Alguna idea chicos? que estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias de antemano, y perdón por el tocho.
No sé si he utilizado bien el tag de code en el foro, es mi primera vez, de no ser así mis disculpas de antemano.
Saludos

Comment: que versión de lua estas usando ? por ejemplo si he entendido bien yo en un caso parecido uso una variable `local file = tostring(line) .. ".txt"` usando los .. para indexar strings , luego ya `io.popen(file)` y no da ningún error.